# How to change search url produced by <form>'s GET method?

Tags: url-rewriting, redirect

I'm developing 'multi category select search form'.
And make it like this

```
<form role="search" action="http://localhost:5757/alpool/" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="alp-search" value="true">
    <div class="ui fluid search dropdown huge selection multiple">
      <select name="cat_s[]" multiple="multiple"> 
        <option value=""> Select Category </option>
        <option value="358">Apple</option>
        <option value="399">Banana</option>
        <option value="359">Water</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="ui primary basic button">검색</button>
</form>
```

And, when I select 'Apple' and 'Banana' my browser show me this.

```
http://localhost:5757/alpool/?alp-search=true&cat_s%5B%5D=358&cat_s%5B%5D=399
```

My question are these.

1. What is %5B%5D ?
2. How can I change the url like this

   `http://localhost:5757/alpool/?alp-search=true&cat_s=358,399`

(should I use javascript? or PHP?)

Thanks.

Comment: %5B is '[' and %5D is ']'

Comment: Yes, you'd need to use JavaScript to "change" the URL. But why would you do that?

Comment: sorry, but this is not **specific** to wordpress.. Anyway, the way to do the url is to use the category selection just as UI (maybe even as a simple UL list), and populate a hidden input that will actually carry your desired info in the format you like

Comment: @SallyCJ because it looks more simple and clean

Comment: @ByeonginYoon [Here's an example](https://jsbin.com/texigecoja/edit?html,js,output) of how you can do it. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question are these.
>
> 1. What is %5B%5D ?
> 2. How can I change the url like this
>
>    `http://localhost:5757/alpool/?alp-search=true&cat_s=358,399`

1. `%5B` and `%5D` are *percent-encoded*/URL-encoded version of the `[` (left square bracket) and `]` (right square bracket) characters, respectively. See [Percent-encoding reserved characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters) on Wikipedia.
2. You can "change" it using JavaScript, and here's an example of how you can do that without making major changes to the `form` markup that you currently have:

   - The only change you need to do is add `alp-search-form` to the `class` attribute of the `form`. The rest can/should remain the same.
   - This method works both with and without JavaScript; but of course, without JavaScript, you'll get the "ugly" URL having those URL-encoded square brackets.

**The JS Script**

```
jQuery( function( $ ) {
  $( '.alp-search-form' ).on( 'submit', function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var url = $( this ).attr( 'action' ),
      cat_ids = $( 'select[name="cat_s[]"]', this ).val() || [],
      s = /\?[a-z0-9]+/i.test( url ) ? '&' : '?';

    url += s + 'alp-search=true';
    url += '&cat_s=' + cat_ids.join( ',' );

    // "Submits" the form.
    //location.href = url; // Uncomment after done testing.
    alert( url );          // Remove this after done testing.
  } );
} );
```

[Demo on JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/texigecoja/edit?html,js,output)

**Additional Note**

In the PHP script/`function` that processes the form data (or handle the search), you can use this snippet (which uses the [`wp_parse_id_list()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_parse_id_list/) function in WordPress) to grab the selected category IDs:

```
// This variable will/should always be an array.
$cat_ids = isset( $_GET['cat_s'] ) ?
    wp_parse_id_list( $_GET['cat_s'] ) : array();
```

Answer (score 0):

%5B%5D is urlencoded for `[]`, as specified with `cat_s[]`.

If you want it have it submit as comma-separated, I think you'd have to use some JavaScript to modify the submitted result (onsubmit event, modify/add variable that contains comma-separated values).

PHP can also read the array without client-side JavaScript (if you're submitting to a PHP page).

Comment: umm, Is there any library about that ?